# Java command line argument: Simple print not working with "@%&^%" (without quotes). Please explain

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

Here's a Java class named Test:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(args[0]);
    }
}
```

When I compile and run it with the argument "Bob", without the quotes, like: `java Test.java Bob` , it runs fine and prints "Hi, Bob. How are you?". On the Terminal, it goes smoothly:

```
xyz@my-iMac src % java Test.java Bob    
Bob
```

Now when I use argument "@%&^%", without the quotes, like: `java Test.java @%&^%` , I get this on my Terminal:

```
xyz@my-iMac src % java Test.java @%&^%
[1] 12097
zsh: command not found: ^%
xyz@my-iMac src % @%
[1]  + done       java Test.java @%
xyz@my-iMac src %
```

I am using **MacOS Terminal zsh** to compile and run java. Username on Macos is **xyz**, Name of iMac is **my-iMac**. The file Test.java is in folder src.

My guess is it's the Terminal doing funny stuff. But I don't know what or I could be wrong.

Please could someone explain what's going on.

Comment: Those characters actually mean something to zsh. Putting them in quotes tell zsh to ignore the special meaning.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks for the quick answer :) Yes, I also thought so and already tried with quotes, which worked fine as you said. I guess the follow up question of "what's exactly happening in Terminal" is then off-topic. As I see you have much more experience, could you tell me if I should ask another question? Or add a keyword "zsh" to this question? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your shell will see the `&` as a control character and not part of one argument. You could also do `@%\&^%`

Comment: This is standard “Unix shell” behavior.  I would suggest you read a good shell tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `&` means "run this in the background" in most shells.

Then zsh tries to execute the next thing which is `^%` which is indeed a non existing command.

If you put quotes (as you tried already) or protect the `&` with a `\` then it would work

```
java Test.java @%\&^%
@%&^%
```